# Firefox opens a new tab instead of javascript code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a web site with this element:

```
<a id="ProPayHyperLink" href="javascript:$ProPay.playIntro('ProPay');" target="_blank">ProPay Payment Center</a>
```

In Chrome, it successfully runs the `$ProPay.playIntro` script. However, when I run the site in FireFox or IE, I get a new blank tab. Using debugger, I can see that it never gets to the `javascript` code.

I am running IE 11 and Firefox 30.0

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I use `target="_blank"` because the `javascript` `href` is temporary and only for specific situations, and because it didn't cause issues in Chrome. I can always add and remove it as needed though.

Comment: Why dont you remove the target blank?

Comment: `javascript URI Scheme` is unofficial but common used `URI scheme`. So browsers can support it differently.

Comment: @doniyor that fixed it for me http://jsfiddle.net/4T63p/

Comment: @andrew in ff and ie also?

Comment: @doniyor, see my update for an explanation. Removing it also fixed it for me in both. I guess I will just add it as needed. I wish the browsers were consistent.

Comment: @davids im also ff 30 and http://jsfiddle.net/4T63p/ works fine

Comment: @doniyor, I can't believe I overlooked trying something so simple. If you put it in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: So then use it without target, as Pinal says, browsers support it differently. The only easy solution seems to be this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove target blank, as Pinal says, browsers support it differently.

```
<a id="ProPayHyperLink" href="javascript:$ProPay.playIntro('ProPay');" >ProPay Payment Center</a>
```

I am in train, sorry for not full answer.